# Getting settings object from the buildscript

Tags: gradle, settings, project

I am trying to access the settings object from the root project's build script.

The reason is I want to define a list in the settings.gradle file which will be a list of subprojects, kind of:

**settings.gradle**

```
projectNames = ['prjA', 'prjB']
```

Would like to do something like:

**build.gradle** (root project)

```
projectNames = settings.projectNames
// Use projectName in tasks
```

And then access it in build.gradle for various tasks, such as resolving those names into URLs to git-clone them. However I can't seem to find a way to declare some arbitrary groovy object which is visible between these two scripts. Note I may potentially like that list to be related but not equal to the project names. I guess the question sums up to sharing POGOs between those two files and accessing the settings object.

I'm pretty new to Gradle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a way to get to the `settings` object from a build script. However, both scripts share a `gradle` object, which you could use to set an extra property in the settings script (e.g. `gradle.ext.foo = "bar"`), and read it in the build script (e.g. `println gradle.foo`).

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't add and ext to gradle.  Got any working coding example that shows this solution?  I'm using kts.

Answer (score 2):

If you need access to the Settings instance from your build.gradle file after the
settings have been loaded and evaluated, you can register a lifecycle closure or listener.
A great place to start is the method Gradle#settingsEvaluated(Closure)
that provides the Settings object as a closure parameter.

Comment: That's an interesting approach!  Have you been able to implement your suggestion.  I was only able to get the settingsEvaluated to be triggered only when its closure is defined in the setting file.  The problem is that the gradle.build script needs to get the settings object.  At the time it triggers, you have access to ProjectDescriptor but not to Project, so you can't pass settings as an extension value.  A working coding example would be helpful. I think you'll still run into the issue that Peter describes.